# Using split with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, split

I am using a site's API to retrieve the following information:

```
5097,2593,1289766548 1541,99,65990390 934,99,73230517 3055,99,62377700
1410,99,81193882 1232,99,50959566 340,99,31225295 2303,99,46585590
91,99,200000000 2258,99,32250727 692,99,40608716 4397,99,23545788
2371,99,30486082 408,99,33064494 136,99,54937860 2410,99,23192056
858,99,30378477 1088,99,21174680 174,99,76296917 477,99,50883493
2577,99,24367856 603,99,34401457 1556,99,24433483 1115,99,22150489
1365,99,23373048 4889,120,121954995 10957,97,10702990 -1,-1 -1,-1
9460,3985121 -1,-1 -1,-1 25908,1608 17180,1538 19932,1519 33486,1651
-1,-1 2589,401 14280,1262 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 34212,360000 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1
```

Note that the numbers are in sets of 3, separated by commas, then a space, then to the next set.

```
xxxx,xxxx,xxxxxxxxxx yyyy,yy,yyyyyyyy zzzz,zz,zzzzzzzz
```

Here is my controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    require 'open-uri'

    @username = "brink"
    @url = "http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=#{@username}"
    @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
  end

  def help
  end
end
```

Here is how I am putting out the information in the view:

```
<h1>Welcome to xpTrack</h1>

<p>
  <%= @username.capitalize %>
</p>

<%= @doc.text %>
```

Is there a way for me to create an array that splits at each space between each set of numbers? I have tried:

`@stats = @doc.split('\n')`, but that returns:

```
undefined method `split' (some Nokogiri error)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
# split on spaces
@stats = @doc.text.split(' ')
# => ["xxxx,xxxx,xxxxxxxxxx","yyyy,yy,yyyyyyyy","zzzz,zz,zzzzzzzz"]

# split on spaces and then on commas
@stats = @doc.text.split(' ').map { |a| a.split(",") }
# => [["xxxx","xxxx","xxxxxxxxxx"],["yyyy","yy","yyyyyyyy"],["zzzz","zz","zzzzzzzz"]]
```

Comment: This got the job done. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Using the second option, how do I reference an element within an array? Now that I've split up everything by spaces **and** commas, how do I put out the first number in the first array?

Comment: @DylanRichards: `@stats[0][0]` will give you the first element of first sub-array.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Nokogiri unless you expect XML or HTML. Just use `open().read` to get a string, and split it up.

Also, I suspect `.scan(/(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)/)`, or some variation thereof, will work better than split.